# Visual Studio. Отсутствует меню создания ASP.NET проекта

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net

При попытке создания проекта *ASP.NET* в *Visual Studio* в пути

> ФАЙЛ > Создать > Проект > Веб

отсутствует меню создания проектов *ASP.NET*. На его месте находится элемент `WebTemplate`. При создания проекта данного типа (`WebTemplate`), *Visual Studio* выдаёт ошибку.

Как **должно** выглядеть:

[image]

Как это у меня выглядит:

[image]

Версия *Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3*.
Web компоненты присутствуют.
Пробовал делать *Repair* (так как *Repair* от онлайн установщика *Visual Studio 2015 Update 3* был недоступен, я использовал версии *Update 0*).

Comment: Поставьте поверх студии web developer - тынц: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd537667%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Это будет как отдельный IDE? Тогда в этом нет смысла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переустановка **Visual Studio** помогла решить данную проблему.
После удаления, я удалил все директории принадлежащие **Visual Studio**.

Такие как:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0`

Очистил реестр от нерабочих значений, прочистил жесткий диск на файлы `.tmp`, `.old` и так далее при помощи утилиты WinTools.net.

На место старой **Visual Studio 2015 Update 3** начал установку **Visual Studio 2015 *[без обновлений]***, к счастью, установщик сам установил необходимые компоненты и обновления. Сейчас сижу на **Visual Studio 2015 Update 3**.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте скачать и установить [Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935) и поставить через консоль NuGet следующее ([Microsoft ASP.NET MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.mvc/)):

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.3
```

Думаю, что во время установки IDE Вы не выбрали WEB-разработку или что-то в этом роде. Также у Вас есть возможность перейти по ссылке (на Вашем скриншоте):

> Щелкните здесь для поиска шаблонов в Интернете.

Введите что Вас интересует в поле поиска и установите то, чего Вам не хватает.

И еще один вариант решения Вашей проблемы:

1. Запустить файл установки среды разработки ( Панель управления -> Программы и компоненты -> Выбрать `VisualStudio` и нажать ***Изменить***)
2. Выбрать `Web Development` в списке устанавливаемых дополнений
3. Установить компоненты и перезагрузить компьютер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Крайний случай

> Если не помогают ни какие варианты решения данной проблемы, то
>   возможно придется полностью удалить VS, абсолютно все ее части и
>   ставить заново с официального образа от Microsoft.

Comment: В том то и проблема, что я установил пакеты для Web разработки. Даже присутствует директория в соответствующей папки IDE.

Comment: @PlasticBlock, NuGet-пакеты поставить пробовали? Если NuGet не помогут - пробуйте обновить IDE или дополнить через панель управления, как я описал в своем ответе.

Comment: Попробовал, ничего не вышло.
http://pastebin.com/SJdGuq64 - ссылка на файл логирования.
До сих пор не могу понять, почему у меня постоянно IDE так сходит сума. Как уже писал выше, несколько раз пробовал сделать Repair. Все компоненты добавлены.

Comment: http://screenshot.su/img/db/3a/17/db3a17c195e6dbc43d1f2ff49e7b796f.jpg
Тут собственно тоже, какая та магия, непонятно откуда появилось 11 МБ, которых невозможно установить.

Comment: @PlasticBlock, вот уж магия...в таком случае, если не помогают ни какие варианты решения данной проблемы, то возможно придется полностью сносить VS, абсолютно все ее части и ставить заново с официального образа от Microsoft. Как-то была проблема с обновлением VS2015 до Update2 и у меня IDE просто легла после обновления. Только переустановка с заведомо полным удалением IDE помогла. Никакие обновления не решили мою проблему. Что будете пробовать делать?

Comment: Тогда оставлю на ночь, на переустановку. Благодарю за ответ и помощь, может кому поможет, отмечу как "Правильный".

Comment: @PlasticBlock, довольно таки интересная ситуация иногда возникает с VS. Особенно после обновления среды разработки.

Answer (score 2):

Если у Вас та же проблема, что и у меня - то .Net Core при установке требует строго определённую версию VS2015 Update 3, но уже установлен более свежий апдейт. Я решил так:
1. Скачал [.NET Core 1.0.0 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817245)
2. Запустил его с параметром SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1

Comment: Скачал и запустил с данным параметром `"C:\Users\Plastic Block\Downloads\DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe" -SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1`. Но к сожалению, пакет выдал ошибку.
http://pastebin.com/SJdGuq64 - ссылка на файл логирования.

Answer (score 0):

У меня Visual Studio Community 2017. Я решил эту проблему следующим образом.

В меню
Средства->Получить средства и компонены
Этот момен появится окно с некоторыми компонентами. Выбираем нужные. Далее нажимаем "изменить". После установки длстаточно перезагрузить среду.